# Copy command with `cp -f -R` strangely does not work on all OS X machines

Tags: bash, macos, shell, copy, osx-elcapitan

I am on *OS X El Capitan*. I have 2 directories `SourceDir` & `DestDir` with the following structures.

```
ParentDir/SourceDir |-s_dir1/ss_dir1
                    |-s_dir2

ParentDir/DestDir |-s_dir1/ss_dir2
                  |-ddir1
                  |-ddir2
                  |-ddir3
```

I want to do a copy command in such a way that `s_dir1` in `ParentDir/SourceDir` gets merged with `s_dir1` in `ParentDir/DestDir` and additionally, `s_dir2` gets placed into `ParentDir/DestDir`. So, after the copy `ParentDir/DestDir` should look like this:

```
ParentDir/DestDir |-s_dir1/ss_dir1
                  |-s_dir1/ss_dir2
                  |-s_dir2
                  |-ddir1
                  |-ddir2
                  |-ddir3
```

I use the following command to copy:
`cp -f -R ParentDir/SourceDir/ ParentDir/DestDir/`

It works all fine on MacOS *Sierra*. But strangely it doesn't work on an OS X machine with *MacOS El Capitan*. Again, I tried it with a *MacOS El Capitan* on my colleague's machine. It worked fine!!!

What is wrong?

**Do different versions of *MacOS El Capitan* behave differently to `cp command`?**

Or, do I need to change the copy command syntax on *El Capitan*?

**How can I do a copy command on my *MacOS El Capitan* machine to ensure the correct recursive copy at least on all OSX machines?**

Please do not suggest to upgrade the *El Capitan* machine to *Sierra*. That is not an option for me. Hence posted this question to get some other syntax options of `copy command`.

Comment: "does not work" doesn't describe what is happening. Without knowing what is actually happening, it's extremely hard to debug anything. In any case, try `command cp -f -R ParentDir/SourceDir/ ParentDir/DestDir/`, that will eliminate some potential problems.

Comment: @janos the command you have typed is exactly the command I am trying as I stated in the question. about your point - "does not work doesn't describe what is happening", the copy command simply doesn't copy anything. neither gives error nor logs anything. just doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't understand. `command` is a shell command. That is, `ls` is different from `command ls`. When you run `ls`, you might be running an alias, not necessarily the real `ls`. When you run `command ls`, with the `command` literally in front of it, that will bypass aliases. I suggest to try `command cp ...` instead of just `cp ...`, to eliminate interference by aliases. As for what happens, if nothing happens, you should explain that clearly in your post, we cannot guess it. And please check the exit code. After running `cp`, run `echo $?`

Comment: Actually, `/bin/cp -f -R ParentDir/SourceDir/` would be even better than the `command` version, since it assures that you're using the version of `cp` that came with the OS, not a version installed with homebrew or something like that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson your suggestion of doing `/bin/cp -f -R` works perfectly !! Any suggestion what I should do ensure the whenever `cp` is called, it executes `/bin/cp` ? Anything that I can do in `.profile` or somewhere ? I am not an expert in these OSX system related command line stuff

Comment: creating an alias as `alias cp="/bin/cp"` in `~/.profile` enforces the cp command to work from bin & hence solves the issue. @GordonDavisson you can please post an answer with the same suggestion as in your comment & I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the standard `cp` command is being overridden by something else. You can force it to use the standard `cp` command by explicitly specifying `/bin/cp`. You could also try to override the current override by using something like an alias, but it'd really be better to find out what the current override is, where it's coming from, and (maybe) getting rid of it.

The first thing to do is run `type cp` its output tells you what `cp` is currently doing:

- If it prints something like "cp is /usr/local/bin/cp", then you've got a custom-installed version of `cp` that's overriding the standard one... and is apparently causing problems. Your best option here is to find out what's installed the nonstandard `cp` command (maybe homebrew?) and remove it.
- If it prints something like "cp is aliased to <some command string>", then you have an alias defined in one of your shell initialization files (or one of the files they run, etc). Check your ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.bashrc for the source of the alias definition.
- If it prints "cp is a function", then you have a function defined in one of your shell init files. Check as you would for an alias definition.

Comment: Does not work here even using **/bin/cp**. Also, **which cp** returns **/bin/cp** which is weird since the **/bin/cp** and **cp** commands here turned out to produce directories with different sizes_ (and none of them right)

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei `which cp` will not show aliases or functions; use `type cp` instead. What exactly is `/bin/cp` doing wrong, and what OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS, right before Monteery. Actually, I the **cp** works correctly (I've beem fooled by **du**, but finder indicates the folders have the same size), but **/bin/cp** made a              folder with 295Mb insted of 285Mb.  Anyway, I am not with tue computer now, but I should update this after I have access to it

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei Calculating (or even defining) the size of a directory can be complicated because of hard links (multiple directory entries for a single actual file) and ["cloned" files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322036/is-it-possible-to-clone-directories-in-apfs) (a feature of the APFS filesystem that allows different files with the same or overlapping contents to share disk space). I'd guess you're seeing complications from one of those rather than something wrong with `/bin/cp` itself.

Answer (score -1):

The trick for me was having to do the `cp` command recursively as super user.

Not sure why

```
sudo /bin/cp -R -v -p source destination
```

the `-v` shows you the progress as each file is copied.

Cheers

Greg